# Complexity of the feasibility and optimization problems

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard

Given an optimization problem $P$, if we know that this optimization problem is NP-hard, is it necessary to check the complexity of the corresponding feasibility problem, i.e. the complexity of checking if the problem admits a feasible solution? Because in the case of $P$ the problem is not always feasible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of checking whether $P$ admits a feasible solution might or might not be NP-hard (both cases are possible).

For example, if $P$ it the problem of finding a vertex cover and the goal is to minimize the number of selected vertices then $P$ is NP-hard but a feasible solutions is trivial (just select all vertices).

On the other hand, if $P$ is the problem of finding a satisfying truth assignment for a $3$-SAT formula and the goal is that of minimizing the number of asserted variables, then both $P$ and the problem of checking whether a feasible solution exists are NP-hard.

Comment: so if the feasibility problem is NP-hard this implies that the optimization problem is also NP-hard